# Superconductor: What form of paramters (like London penetration depth) to use?

Tags: superconductivity

I am dealing with thin film and [LN2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_nitrogen) temperature, and am trying to calculate values such as the [Pearl Length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_vortex), but am trying to find clarification as to which value of $\lambda_L$ to use in this case. e.g.

$\lambda_L(t,T)$ with T = 0 or T = 77K?

I have other formula, such as the kinetic inductance for a CPW, but the articles I am pulling them from are somewhat unclear which forms of the parameters they are using. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: CPW = Co-Planar Waveguide?

Answer (score 1):

Well LN2 boils at 77K - If you want the penetration depth at LN2 temperatures, use T=77K

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I did answer his question (as I understood it). He asks what his temperature parameter should be for calculating the penetration depth, 0K or 77K. Since he is at LN2 temperatures, he should use 77K ...

Comment: @Sklivvz Yes, Brendan answered correctly the question. The temperature of the bath will be the temperature of melting of the nitrogen liquid.

Comment: @Oaoa sure, but the answer does not *explain anything*.

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah ok, I get your point, and I agree. But the question was really precise, not of a general perspective. So the answer is really precise as well :-) If the OP wants a better answer, (s)he can precise her/his mind. (S)He refers to some articles without citations for instance... I think the Brendan answer is the best regarding to the details the OP gave.